# Имеется RSA PRIVATE KEY как им расшифровать зашифрованный текст

Tags: java, android, криптография, rsa

Есть RSA PRIVATE KEY , как с помощью него расшифровать text.
Я знаю , что можно вот так вот , но мой ключ хранится в виде байтов.

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
encryptionByte = cipher.doFinal(encrptdByte);
```

Comment: Подозреваю, что импортирование ключа будет зависеть от того, в каком он у вас формате хранится...

Comment: мне нужно как-то из байтов перегнать в формат PrivateKey

Comment: А в байтах что? PEM/DER/WInAPI blob?

Comment: Если байты конвертнут в строку получу на выходе Begin RSA PRIVATE KEY  и в конце естесвенное END RSA PRIVATE KEY

Answer (score 1):

Пользуясь одним приватным ключом дешифровать невозможно.

Для дешифровки нужна пара ключей: приватный и публичный ключи, причем нужен публичный ключ того от которого получено сообщение.

В асимметричной криптографии имеется специальный алгоритм генерации т.н. `shared` ключа из пары приватный+публичный, причем:

```
shared(private_alice, public_bob)=shared(private_bob, public_alice);
//Алиса шифрует сообщение комбинацией своего приватного ключа и публичного ключа Боба
//Боб дешифрует сообщение комбинацией своего приватного ключа и публичного ключа Алисы
```

Alice и Bob - условные обозначения реципиентов [принятые в криптографии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%B8_%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B1)

Comment: Не надо путать RSA и протоколы нахождения общего секрета. Для расшифровки RSA достаточно приватного ключа (D, N)

Comment: Ну да, вы правы. В классическом варианте Боб шифрует публичным ключом Алисы, а Алиса дешифрует своим приватным ключом. Я то полагал, что речь идет о варианте когда они оба имеют пару ключей...